# Regex for BIC check

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, bank, iban

I wrote a regex for php function pregmatch which is like this:

```
^([a-zA-Z]){4}([a-zA-Z]){2}([0-9a-zA-Z]){2}([0-9a-zA-Z]{3})?$^
```

Now I need to check the consistency of an BIC string.

Something is wrong with it... it is always correct. And I have no idea why.

The code I use is something like this:

```
/**
 * Checks the correct format from the 
 * @param string $bic
 * @return boolean
 */
public function checkBic($bic)
{
    $bic = $this->cleanFromSeparators($bic);
    if (preg_match($this->getBicCompare(), $bic)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

private function getBicCompare()
{
    return "^([a-zA-Z]){4}([a-zA-Z]){2}([0-9a-zA-Z]){2}([0-9a-zA-Z]{3})?$^";
}
```

EDIT:

Here are some references for BIC format from the swift account:

http://www.sage.co.uk/sage1000v2_1/form_help/workingw/subfiles/iban_and_bic.htm

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_9362

http://www.swift.com/products_services/bic_and_iban_format_registration_bic_details?rdct=t

an example BIC would be:

NOLADE21STS

OPSKATWW

The regex should only return true if the string consists of the following code:
its length is eight or eleven characters and that consists of:

Bank code - 4 alphabetic characters
Country code - 2 letters
Location code - 2 alphanumeric characters, except zero
Branch code - 3 alphanumeric characters

These are the specifications.

So the length can be either 11 or 8, first 4 can be anything, then 2 letters is a must, then 2 numbers and optional 3 alphanumeric.

The following are not valid:

abcdefxx

abcdefxxyyy

These also are not valid:

aaaa11xx

aaaa11xxyyy

and so on.

Comment: can you please give more info? eg how a correct BIC should and should not look ...

Comment: Will to :) just a moment

Comment: @Sangoku Could you give us examples of what shouldn't work but did?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You are using `^` as delimiter? You probably want something more like:

```
'/^[a-z]{6}[0-9a-z]{2}([0-9a-z]{3})?\z/i'
```

Comment: "*When using the PCRE functions, it is required that the pattern is enclosed by delimiters. A delimiter can be any non-alphanumeric, non-backslash, non-whitespace character.*" [Source](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php). It shouldn't be a problem to use `^` as a delimiter.

Comment: @Loamhoof, it's a problem because he wants to anchor the expression. That's why I guess `^` is used as first character.

Comment: To be honest .... tht was just coincidence... i started the regex as ^()^ piggy :)

Comment: @Qtax surely he wants to do that, but without an example of what's matching while it should not, we can't be sure it's the real problem. (I guess `^^` should work, but still be ugly.)

Comment: @Loamhoof, `^^` wouldn't work, you'd need to escape the anchor in that case, like `^\^`, but I'm unsure if that would get you the literal or the meta meaning of the character in PHP. In that case probably clearer to use `^\A`.

Comment: Yeah you're right. Well, anyway we'll have to wait for an OP update.

Comment: gave not valid and valid examples.

Comment: Almost ok but i made some adjustments to it and now it is perfect :)

Comment: PHP snippet `$result_bic = (bool) ( preg_match('/^[a-z]{6}[0-9a-z]{2}([0-9a-z]{3})?\z/i', $bic) == 1 );`

Answer (score 9):

> Structure
>
> The latest edition is ISO 9362:2009 (dated 2009-10-01). The SWIFT code
>   is 8 or 11 characters, made up of:
>
> 4 letters: Institution Code or bank code.
>
> 2 letters: ISO 3166-1 alpha-2 country code
>
> 2 letters or digits: location code
>
> if the second character is "0", then it is typically a test BIC as
>   opposed to a BIC used on the live network. if the second character is
>   "1", then it denotes a passive participant in the SWIFT network if the
>   second character is "2", then it typically indicates a reverse billing
>   BIC, where the recipient pays for the message as opposed to the more 
>   usual mode whereby the sender pays for the message.
>
> 3 letters or digits: branch code, optional ('XXX' for primary
>   office)

(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_9362)

(different definition in German-Wiki http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_9362)

> 2 letters or digits: location code
>   The first character must not be the digit "0" or "1".
>   The letter 'O' is not allowed as a second character.
>   (Regex for this definition: [2-9a-z][0-9a-np-z])

```
'/^[a-z]{6}[2-9a-z][0-9a-np-z]([a-z0-9]{3}|x{3})?$/i'
```

Comment: Adding a breakdown of how the separate sections of your regex relate to the specification would be useful.

Comment: The German Wikipedia also says that the optional branch name must not start with an "X" except when it's XXX. Then the regex would be `'/^[A-Z]{6}[2-9A-Z][0-9A-NP-Z](XXX|[0-9A-WYZ][0-9A-Z]{2})?$/i'`

Answer (score 7):

This is the official SEPA pattern for validating BIC

```
[A-Z]{6,6}[A-Z2-9][A-NP-Z0-9]([A-Z0-9]{3,3}){0,1}
```

Comment: where did you found that?

Comment: That matches words like `SCHEDULE` and `Websense` for example, not recommended. The answer from @serraine above at least is accurate even if inefficient.

Answer (score 2):

I think this one would do:

```
/^[a-z0-9]{4}[a-z]{2}\d{2}([a-z0-9]{3})?$/
```

That is:

1. start of string, `^`
2. four alphanumeric chars, `[a-z0-9]{4}`
3. two numbers, `\d{2}`
4. three optional (`?` suffix) alphanumerich chars, `([a-z0-9]{3})?`
5. end of string, `$`

You can see it in action and test it [here](http://regexr.com?34fk6) (I used your samples).
Anyway, from the rules you are reporting, `OPSKATWW` shouldn't be a valid BIC since it has no numbers after the first 6 letters.

Comment: I need the z/i to make sure it is case insensitive. the \d{2} part is good. will note it. /d decimal. nice one.

Comment: Sorry, I meant `/^[a-z0-9]{4}[a-z]{2}\d{2}([a-z0-9]{3})?$/i`. What is the `z` for? Anyway, you could also do a `$bic=strtolower($bic)` before testing it against this regex.

Answer (score 1):

**I do not recommend using this as it's lacking performance**, but in case someone needs to verify IBANS also against [ISO-3366-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1) country codes:

```
/^[A-Z]{4}(AC|AD|AE|AF|AG|AI|AL|AM|AN|AO|AQ|AR|AS|AT|AU|AW|AX|AZ|BA|BB|BD|BE|BF|BG|BH|BI|BJ|BL|BM|BN|BO|BQ|BR|BS|BT|BV|BW|BY|BZ|CA|CC|CD|CE|CF|CG|CH|CI|CK|CL|CM|CN|CO|CP|CR|CS|CU|CV|CW|CX|CY|CZ|DD|DE|DG|DJ|DK|DM|DO|DZ|EA|EC|EE|EG|EH|ER|ES|ET|EU|FI|FJ|FK|FM|FO|FR|FX|GA|GB|GD|GE|GF|GG|GH|GI|GL|GM|GN|GP|GQ|GR|GS|GT|GU|GW|GY|HK|HM|HN|HR|HT|HU|IC|ID|IE|IL|IM|IN|IO|IQ|IR|IS|IT|JE|JM|JO|JP|KE|KG|KH|KI|KM|KN|KP|KR|KW|KY|KZ|LA|LB|LC|LI|LK|LR|LS|LT|LU|LV|LY|MA|MC|MD|ME|MF|MG|MH|MK|ML|MM|MN|MO|MP|MQ|MR|MS|MT|MU|MV|MW|MX|MY|MZ|NA|NC|NE|NF|NG|NI|NL|NO|NP|NR|NT|NU|NZ|OM|PA|PE|PF|PG|PH|PK|PL|PM|PN|PR|PS|PT|PW|PY|QA|RE|RO|RS|RU|RW|SA|SB|SC|SD|SE|SF|SG|SH|SI|SJ|SK|SL|SM|SN|SO|SR|SS|ST|SU|SV|SX|SY|SZ|TA|TC|TD|TF|TG|TH|TJ|TK|TL |TM|TN|TO|TP|TR|TT|TV|TW|TZ|UA|UG|UK|UM|US|UY|UZ|VA|VC|VE|VG|VI|VN|VU|WF|WS|XK|YE|YT|ZA|ZM|ZR|ZW)[2-9A-Z][0-9A-NP-Z](XXX|[0-9A-WYZ][0-9A-Z]{2})?$/i
```

Also this is content validation and not just format validation.
But it will save you a bit of code :)

Comment: What question are you answering?

Answer (score 1):

```
echo preg_match('/^[A-Z]{4}(AC|AD|AE|AF|AG|AI|AL|AM|AN|AO|AQ|AR|AS|AT|AU|AW|AX|AZ|BA|BB|BD|BE|BF|BG|BH|BI|BJ|BL|BM|BN|BO|BQ|BR|BS|BT|BV|BW|BY|BZ|CA|CC|CD|CE|CF|CG|CH|CI|CK|CL|CM|CN|CO|CP|CR|CS|CU|CV|CW|CX|CY|CZ|DD|DE|DG|DJ|DK|DM|DO|DZ|EA|EC|EE|EG|EH|ER|ES|ET|EU|FI|FJ|FK|FM|FO|FR|FX|GA|GB|GD|GE|GF|GG|GH|GI|GL|GM|GN|GP|GQ|GR|GS|GT|GU|GW|GY|HK|HM|HN|HR|HT|HU|IC|ID|IE|IL|IM|IN|IO|IQ|IR|IS|IT|JE|JM|JO|JP|KE|KG|KH|KI|KM|KN|KP|KR|KW|KY|KZ|LA|LB|LC|LI|LK|LR|LS|LT|LU|LV|LY|MA|MC|MD|ME|MF|MG|MH|MK|ML|MM|MN|MO|MP|MQ|MR|MS|MT|MU|MV|MW|MX|MY|MZ|NA|NC|NE|NF|NG|NI|NL|NO|NP|NR|NT|NU|NZ|OM|PA|PE|PF|PG|PH|PK|PL|PM|PN|PR|PS|PT|PW|PY|QA|RE|RO|RS|RU|RW|SA|SB|SC|SD|SE|SF|SG|SH|SI|SJ|SK|SL|SM|SN|SO|SR|SS|ST|SU|SV|SX|SY|SZ|TA|TC|TD|TF|TG|TH|TJ|TK|TL|TM|TN|TO|TP|TR|TT|TV|TW|TZ|UA|UG|UK|UM|US|UY|UZ|VA|VC|VE|VG|VI|VN|VU|WF|WS|XK|YE|YT|ZA|ZM|ZR|ZW)[2-9A-Z][0-9A-NP-Z]([A-Z0-9]{3}|x{3})?$/',$val);
```

Answer (score 1):

The most recent [ISO 9362:2022(E)](https://www.iso.org/standard/84108.html) allows the following strings as BICs:

```
^[A-Z0-9]{4}[A-Z]{2}[A-Z0-9]{2}(?:[A-Z0-9]{3})?$
```

Note: Only upper-case letters are allowed; so don’t ignoreCase.

---

If one wishes, one could check against the list of country codes:

```
^[A-Z0-9]{4}(?:AD|AE|AF|AG|AI|AL|AM|AO|AQ|AR|AS|AT|AU|AW|AX|AZ|BA|BB|BD|BE|BF|BG|BH|BI|BJ|BL|BM|BN|BO|BQ|BR|BS|BT|BV|BW|BY|BZ|CA|CC|CD|CF|CG|CH|CI|CK|CL|CM|CN|CO|CR|CU|CV|CW|CX|CY|CZ|DE|DJ|DK|DM|DO|DZ|EC|EE|EG|EH|ER|ES|ET|FI|FJ|FK|FM|FO|FR|GA|GB|GD|GE|GF|GG|GH|GI|GL|GM|GN|GP|GQ|GR|GS|GT|GU|GW|GY|HK|HM|HN|HR|HT|HU|ID|IE|IL|IM|IN|IO|IQ|IR|IS|IT|JE|JM|JO|JP|KE|KG|KH|KI|KM|KN|KP|KR|KW|KY|KZ|LA|LB|LC|LI|LK|LR|LS|LT|LU|LV|LY|MA|MC|MD|ME|MF|MG|MH|MK|ML|MM|MN|MO|MP|MQ|MR|MS|MT|MU|MV|MW|MX|MY|MZ|NA|NC|NE|NF|NG|NI|NL|NO|NP|NR|NU|NZ|OM|PA|PE|PF|PG|PH|PK|PL|PM|PN|PR|PS|PT|PW|PY|QA|RE|RO|RS|RU|RW|SA|SB|SC|SD|SE|SG|SH|SI|SJ|SK|SL|SM|SN|SO|SR|SS|ST|SV|SX|SY|SZ|TC|TD|TF|TG|TH|TJ|TK|TL|TM|TN|TO|TR|TT|TV|TW|TZ|UA|UG|UM|US|UY|UZ|VA|VC|VE|VG|VI|VN|VU|WF|WS|YE|YT|ZA|ZM|ZW)[A-Z0-9]{2}(?:[A-Z0-9]{3})?$
```

Please keep the performance in mind as already mentioned by [serraine](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7289735/serraine).

#fyi One can find the list of country codes here: https://www.iso.org/obp/ui.

Answer (score -3):

Ok. to all who have the same problems with this kind of problem the correct regex is:

```
/^[0-9a-z]{4}[a-z]{2}[0-9a-z]{2}([0-9a-z]{3})?\z/i
```

thy @Qtax for providing it. i just refined it a bit.

Edit the tweak was that i changed it so the first 4 letters can be alphanumeric, but the 2 letters after it have to represent a international code for a country. That is why only letters. And i checked it with actual users who have real use codes. They can have numeric values in first 4 positions.

**Edit:**

I was in wrong. the firtst 4 cann be only letters. I was relaying on an statment of a employe from Reifeisen Bank with wich i was discussing the standard. It turner out he was thinking the number of the bank from their internal no idea what system cann be a valid code. As it turned out that is not the case.

So the correct sintax is

```
/^{6}[a-z]{2}[0-9a-z]{2}([0-9a-z]{3})?\z/i
```

Will mark the correct answer. Thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: Why did you add digits to the first 4 characters? That's not in your question and not in the linked spec either.

Comment: That is the code for country and a nummber. Trust me this one is ok :)

Comment: To all who keep grading with minus 4 letters can contain numbers for some countries, but there HAS to be a 2 nuber digit on end of it or the check will fail for the bank. I have direct call to bank api after this call.

Comment: The last regex from Sangoki is *not* correct. The first four characters of a BIC need to be letters NOT numbers. I think the correct one would be: /^[a-z]{4}[a-z]{2}[0-9a-z]{2}([0-9a-z]{3})?\z/i Or - to make it shorter /^[a-z]{6}[0-9a-z]{2}([0-9a-z]{3})?\z/i

Comment: Not anymore. The first four characters can be digits. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/73048163/1249581.